# How to display a squared outline on input range/slider thumb

Tags: html, css, range, slider

I have a custom styled range input slider. I'm looking to apply an outline to the slider's thumb/handle when it is focused through keyboard but unable to do so.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width: 30%;">
  <input type="range" class="styled-slider slider-progress" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type="range"].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:focus-visible {
  outline: 2px solid black;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}

input[type="range"].styled-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb:focus {
  outline: 2px solid black;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}
```

But it looks like the pseudo-element `::-webkit-slider-thumb` isn't focusable by default. Though if I have shadow DOM enabled in Chrome DevTools and I set the :focus or :focus-visible states through DevTools then it works.

[Slider thumb with rounded outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7tRm.png)

Which brings me to my second question, how to have an outline that is square/rectangle on a rounded slider thumb? Is that even possible? Something like below:

[Slider thumb with squared outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzTDg.png)

CodePen: https://codepen.io/k171/pen/mdGYxGB

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to make it have that specific outline would be to add some `padding` and then set the `background-clip` property to `content-box`.

To make it have a square shape, just play with the `border-radius` property.

```css
input[type=range] {
  height: 39px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #A6A6A6;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #F27B7F;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -11px;
  
  padding: 10px;
  background-clip: content-box
  
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 30%;">
  <input type="range" class="styled-slider slider-progress" />
</div>
```